# Import data from sqlite3 database file to Room database on runtime

Tags: android, backup, android-room, database-backups

I'm trying to implement import / export functionality for my app, which uses a Room database.
Exporting is implemented by just copying the database file given by `getDatabasePath`, but I've hit a problem when implementing the Import functionality.

I've tried using `Room.databaseBuilder(...).createFromFile()` but it does not help, since it only works when creating the database.
I've looked at other answers to similar questions which suggest overwriting the database file, but I'd preferably like something a bit less "hacky" (When I tried it it didn't seem to work either).

If possible, importing the data should be:

- Destructive - remove all prior data in the room database.
- possible from a File, Uri or InputStream.
- Possible on runtime, so users don't need to restart the app.

Hopefully, I won't need to manually transfer the data between the databases.

Answer (score 0):

Try overwriting your database file from `getDatabasePath` with the backup file you exported.

You might have to restart the app after this.